# Updated global variable not being passed to function inside a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, lottie

So I have these:

```
var containerId = 'anim1'

var animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
  container: document.getElementById(containerId),
  renderer: 'svg',
  loop: false,
  autoplay: false,
  path: "https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_rd4wrn81.json"
});

function playanim() {
  animation.goToAndPlay(0);
}

$('div').on('click', function() {
  containerId = $(this).attr('id');
  $('#text').text(containerId + ' was just clicked');
  playanim();
})
```

The global variable `containerId` is being updated on click events, however the updated value is not being passed to the same `containerId` within the variable `animation`. Not sure if it's a bodymovin specific issue- how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

In the line that begins `var animation = ...`, you are creating an object, setting its `container` property to `document.getElementById(containerId)` (using whatever value `containerId` has at that time, i.e. `'anim1'`) and then passing that object to bodymovin.loadAnimation (presumably as a configuration - I'm unfamiliar w/that library)

When the div is clicked, the value of `containerId` is being updated, but this is not changing the value of the `container` property in the config object you created earlier; that's still equal to `anim1`. And even if it did change, it might not make any difference unless bodymovin is monitoring that config object. It's quite possible that bodymovin.loadAnimation just checks the value of `container` when it's initialized, and then never checks it again.

It might achieve what you want if you rebuild the animation every time the div is clicked, e.g. something like this (you might want to stop the animation in the old div as well?)

```
var animation    // just declare it for now, assign below

// The following function will load the animation to the specified container
function setAnimation (containerId) {
  console.log ("Loading animation into " + containerId)
  animation = bodymovin.loadAnimation({
    container: document.getElementById(containerId),
    renderer: 'svg',
    loop: false,
    autoplay: false,
    path: "https://assets10.lottiefiles.com/packages/lf20_rd4wrn81.json"
  });
}

// Load it in 'anim1' first
setAnimation ('anim1')

function playanim() {
  animation.goToAndPlay(0);
}

$('div').on('click', function() {
  var id = $(this).attr('id')
  console.log(id + ' was just clicked');
  $('#text').text(id + ' was just clicked');
  setAnimation (id);  // re-initialize the animation
  animation.addEventListener('data_ready',playanim);
})
```

Without knowing more about bodymovin (sorry), I can't tell if this is a wildly inefficient way to do it. Maybe bodymovin has a more lightweight way of changing the container for an animation that's already loaded, in which case you could just do that in your click handler.

Comment: Hey appreciate the quick response. I've just tried but it doesn't work- it seems like when `animation = bodymovin...` is wrapped inside a function, it just doesn't run, even when everything's a constant

Comment: Unfortunately, I probably can't proceed much further without being able to reproduce your setup, but I did edit my example to fix a minor(?) bug and also print some debug messages to the console output, which might help you figure out what's going on. I also moved the `playanim` call to an event listener, since you probably shouldn't try to play the animation until after it's loaded, and you can't predict that, you just have to wait for bodymovin to tell you (via an event): https://github.com/airbnb/lottie-web#events

Comment: If you want the animation to begin playing in element `anim1` immediately when the code is run, then you should move the line `animation.addEventListener('data_ready',playanim);` from the function at the end into the `setAnimation` function. Though that doesn't seem to be the behavior of your original code, so I'm not sure if that is indeed what you want.